# ¿Por que me sucede el error de que la serie comienza desde 11?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int fib(int n);

int main()

{
    int numero,i;
    cout<<"ingrse el numero de elementos"<<endl;
    for(i=1;i<=numero;i++){
        cout<<i<<fib(i)<<endl;
    }


return 0;
}

int fib(int n){
    if(n==0 || n==1)
        return n;

else{
return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: el problema no tiene nada que ver con [tag:qt], por favor elige bien tus etiquetas. Sería interesante que señales cual es el error.

Answer (score 4):

No hay ningún error de que la serie inicia en 11, lo que pasa es que no estas poniendo ningún separador entre el contador de elementos y el elemento `cout<<i<<fib(i)<<endl;` Adicional, en ese código no pusiste la asignación de la variable numero `cin >> numero;`.

Puse un separador " - ", y arreglando algunos detallitos de espaciado y tabulaciones, debería quedar así.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int fib(int n);

int main() {
    int numero,i;
    cout << "ingrese el numero de elementos: " ;
    cin >> numero;
    for(i=1; i<=numero; i++){
        cout << i << " - " << fib(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int fib(int n){
    if(n==0 || n==1) {
        return n;
    } else {
    return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

La salida:

```
ingrese el numero de elementos: 7
1 - 1
2 - 1
3 - 2
4 - 3
5 - 5
6 - 8
7 - 13
```